# how to separate string according to their character in python?

Tags: python, ascii, non-ascii-characters, punctuation

I am trying to separate characters in a string into three different groups:

1. ASCII
2. String.punctuation
3. characters that don't belong to categories mentioned above.

The string in question is: "Tämä on testi!!! Toimiiko, mitä?"

So far, I have written the following code:

```
import string
osat = "Tämä on testi!!! Toimiiko, mitä?"
x = string.punctuation
a = ""
b = ""
c = ""


for i in osat:
    if i.isascii():
        a += i
    elif i in x:
        b += i
    elif i not in x and i not in a:
        c += i


print(a)
print(b)
print(c)
```

and this piece of code prints this:

```
Tm on testi!!! Toimiiko, mit?

äää
```

Why does the code include eg. "!" in ASCII?
Why doesn't the code add spaces even though the string does have spaces?

Comment: All punctuation characters are in ascii, but not the other way around. You should check for `i in x` first and `i.isascii()` second.

Comment: Exclamation marks and spaces are ascii characters, hence the output you're seeing. If you're trying to find letters and numbers in your original string, I recommend you look into the str.isalnum() function (https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.isalnum)

Comment: Your last `elif` can be just an `else`.   When code gets to that point, you've already proven that it is not in the first groups.   Plus,` isascii` is not what you want if you want alphanumerics.

Comment: As an aside, appending to a string can be inefficient for large strings. You can let `a`, `b` and `c` be lists, append to lists and call `join` when you are done with iteration.

Comment: Just reorder your if-ladder to test for punctuation first, then for (non-punctuation) ASCII, then everything else.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this code:

```
import string
osat = "Tämä on testi!!! Toimiiko, mitä?"
x = string.punctuation
a = ""
b = ""
c = ""
def isnt_ascii(s):
    return all(ord(c) >= 128 for c in s)

for i in osat:
    if is_ascii(i):
        a += i
    elif i in x:
        b += i
    elif i not in x and i not in a:
        c += i


print(a)
print(b)
print(c)
```

is_ascii is good function for this get ascii detailes :

```
def isnt_ascii(s):
    return all(ord(c) >= 128 for c in s)
```

Output:

```
äää
!!!,?
Tm on testi Toimiiko mit
```

Comment: The `is_ascii` function is not correct: `is_ascii("✐") == "✐".isascii()`.

Comment: I edit function name. if we want check is ascii , We must use the < sign in function and otherwise use >=.